# Writing multiline grep results to separate files in zsh and naming files from match capture group

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep, zsh

I want to separate a file into sections and write them into new files.

The file looks like this:

```
# Install dive docker image explorer
RUN wget -q -O dive.deb https://github.com/wagoodman/dive/releases/download/v0.7.2/dive_0.7.2_linux_amd64.deb && \
  dpkg -i dive.deb && \
  rm dive.deb

# Install docker-compose
RUN curl -fsSL "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.0-rc1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
  chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

I want the new files to be named with the word(s) after "Install" on the first line of each section, and then followed by .sh (I want to make them all individual shell scripts)

For example:

> dive-docker-image-explorer.sh
>
> docker-compose.sh

- Notice how I also want to replace the spaces in the file name with dashes.

I have a grep pattern that is able to capture each section successfully:

```
grep -Pzo "# Install (.+?)\nRUN ((\n|.)+?)(?=#)"
```

I want to use the first capture group as the new file name for each grep match (adding .sh at the end and replacing spaces with dashes)

And i want to use the second capture group to populate the file.

I'm guessing awk is the way to go as sed isn't good at working over multiple lines?

Any help constructing this awk method would be greatly appreciated. I'm finding the docs very difficult to sift through...

Comment: Welcome, couple things.  You should take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].  Then in the editor, make sure you format your question using the `{}` icon for code sections.  Read the help on the editor.A well formed question will increase your chances of getting a good answer.  As it is, it is too long, hard to read and too easy to move along.  Make sure that your starting file content, desired file content, current file content and code are clearly identified.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to cleant things up a bit!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing awk is the way to go as sed isn't good at working over multiple lines?

Although I wouldn't generally say that *sed isn't good at working over multiple lines*, `awk` is a good choice.

This extracts the new file name from the comment line, closes the new file at the empty line, and print the remaining lines to the new file:

```
awk '
sub("^# Install *", "") { gsub(" ", "-"); new_file=$0".sh"; next }
/^$/                    { close(new_file); next }
                        { print >new_file }
    ' long-file
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When newfile=$0, does that refer to the first capture group in the sub() portion?

Comment: I'm guessing I need to iterate over the grep matches to make this work? At themoment it's outputting everything to a single file 'new_file' - i tried making ti "$new_file" - did the same thing..

Comment: Hm - for me, the shown code with your original example data did write the files `dive-docker-image-explorer.sh`, `docker-compose.sh` and `fzf.sh`. Did you copy the code exactly, including the quotes? Which `awk --version` and `zsh --version` did you use?

Comment: Regarding your question "_When newfile=$0, does that refer to the first capture group in the sub() portion?_": No, the `$0` refers to the whole content of the Install line after removal of `# Install ` and substitution of spaces with dashes, i. e. the basename of the new file.

Comment: i'm on awk 4.2.1, zsh 5.5.1.

Comment: Excuse me, you didn't answer the question "Did you copy the code exactly…?". And in order to be sure about the input, please post the output of `sed -n '/^#/,/^$/p;/^$/q' long-file|hd`.

Comment: the output of that sed command is an empty line. And yes I copied the awk code you supplied exactly except for the substitution of 'long-file' for the actual file name - which in this case is "Dockerfile"

Comment: Is there an empty line or any other line before the first `# Install` line in "Dockerfile"? Please try and show the output of `sed '/^$/q' Dockerfile|hd`.